# Why isn't my text h3?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying dynamically to add additional text to html. I get the text but it's not in h3. Any ideas why?

```
    let brElement = document.createElement("br");
    let pickCategory = document.createElement("div");
    let h3Element = document.createElement("h3");
    let newPick = document.createTextNode("Изберете категория МПС: ");
    document.body.appendChild(pickCategory.appendChild(brElement.appendChild(h3Element.appendChild(newPick))));
```

The result is: new div, new line the text I want, but not an h3. Why?!

Answer (score 2):

The return value of appendChild is the appended child. Not the parent which is what would be required for your code to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

appendChild returns the child element, so chaining them doesn't work (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
Just make the append multi line and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm. Thank you both:

```
    let brElement = document.createElement("br");
    let pickCategory = document.createElement("div");
    let h3Element = document.createElement("h3");
    let newPick = document.createTextNode("Изберете категория МПС: ");
    h3Element.appendChild(newPick);
    brElement.appendChild(pickCategory);
    pickCategory.appendChild(h3Element);
    document.body.appendChild(pickCategory);
```